# Spring Integration: tests methods fail if executed together

Tags: spring, unit-testing, spring-integration

The workflow of my application is adding a message header, then routing the message depending on another header and sending the message further downstream. My tests for this workflow succeed individually but not when executed together, although it seems that I have reset all relevant objects.

The spring integration workflow:

```
<int:header-enricher input-channel="workflowStart" output-channel="headerEnriched">
    <int:header name="correlationId" expression="headers.id.toString()" />
</int:header-enricher>

<int:header-value-router input-channel="headerEnriched" header-name="messageType">
    <int:mapping value="stp" channel="stpChannel" />
    <int:mapping value="nonStp" channel="nonStpChannel" />
</int:header-value-router>

<int:publish-subscribe-channel id="nonStpChannel"   />
<int:publish-subscribe-channel id="stpChannel" apply-sequence="true"/>

<int:chain input-channel="nonStpChannel" output-channel="systemChannel1" id="nonStpChainBlockA"> 
    <!-- do something -->
</int:chain> 

<int:chain input-channel="stpChannel" output-channel="systemChannel3" id="stpChainBlockA"> 
    <!-- do something -->
</int:chain>
```

The Java test class:

```
@Autowired 
    private MessageChannel workflowStart;
    @Autowired
    private MessageHandler systemChannel1OutputHandler; 
    @Autowired
    private MessageHandler systemChannel3OutputHandler; 

    @Value("/xml/tradeStp.xml")
    private Resource stpMessageResource;
    private String stpMessage;
    @Value("/xml/tradeNonStp.xml")
    private Resource nonStpMessageResource;
    private String nonStpMessage;


    @Before
    public void setup() throws Exception {
        reset(systemChannel1OutputHandler);
        reset(systemChannel3OutputHandler);
        stpMessage = IOUtils.toString(stpMessageResource.getInputStream());
        nonStpMessage = IOUtils.toString(nonStpMessageResource.getInputStream());
    }

    @Test
    public void nonStpMessageWorkflow1Test() {
        Message<String> m = MessageBuilder
                .withPayload(nonStpMessage)
                .setHeaderIfAbsent("messageType", "nonStp")
                .build();       
        workflowStart.send(m);
        verify(systemChannel1OutputHandler, times(1)).handleMessage(any(Message.class));    
    }

    @Test
    public void stpMessageWorkflow2Test() {
        Message<String> m = MessageBuilder
                .withPayload(stpMessage)
                .setHeaderIfAbsent("messageType", "stp")
                .build();
        workflowStart.send(m);
        verify(systemChannel3OutputHandler, times(1)).handleMessage(any(Message.class));
    }
```

And the test context:

```
<import resource="classpath:/spring/workflow.xml"/>

<int:outbound-channel-adapter channel="systemChannel1" ref="systemChannel1OutputHandler" method="handleMessage"/>
<bean id="systemChannel1OutputHandler" class="org.mockito.Mockito" factory-method="mock">
    <constructor-arg value="org.springframework.integration.core.MessageHandler"/>
</bean> 
<int:outbound-channel-adapter channel="systemChannel3" ref="systemChannel3OutputHandler" method="handleMessage"/>
<bean id="systemChannel3OutputHandler" class="org.mockito.Mockito" factory-method="mock">
    <constructor-arg value="org.springframework.integration.core.MessageHandler"/>
</bean>

<int:outbound-channel-adapter channel="headerEnriched" ref="headerEnricherOutputHandler" method="handleMessage"/>
<bean id="headerEnricherOutputHandler" class="org.mockito.Mockito" factory-method="mock">
    <constructor-arg value="org.springframework.integration.core.MessageHandler"/>
</bean>
```

If I run both tests together, the first test succeeds, while the second one fails with the message:

```
    Wanted but not invoked:
messageHandler.handleMessage(<any>);
-> at com.company.integration.com.company.export.config.InterfaceTest.stpMessageWorkflow2Test(InterfaceTest.java:81)
Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.
```

I have tried to debug in various ways. The problem seems to be just after the header-value-router and before the chain. The last debug output for the second test is a "postSend" on the headerEnriched channel. 
Any advice is very welcome.

UPDATE:
I failed to include an additional outputHandler that I have in my context for another test, which I have included now. By removing the headerEnricherOutputHandler all tests run fine. However, I still don't understand the reason why this causes problems when tests are being run together.

Answer (score 0):

I've had problems with Mockito using any(class). Where you have

```
verify(systemChannel3OutputHandler, times(1)).handleMessage(any(Message.class));
```

does it work with if you remove the class, like:

```
verify(systemChannel3OutputHandler, times(1)).handleMessage(any());
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea. This didn't work, as the problem seems to be on the spring side, for some reason the message is not being sent downstream.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce your issue with the following, which does not appear materially different to your tests...

```
<int:header-value-router input-channel="headerEnriched" header-name="messageType">
    <int:mapping value="stp" channel="stpChannel" />
    <int:mapping value="nonStp" channel="nonStpChannel" />
</int:header-value-router>

<int:publish-subscribe-channel id="nonStpChannel"   />
<int:publish-subscribe-channel id="stpChannel" apply-sequence="true"/>

<int:chain input-channel="stpChannel" output-channel="systemChannel1">
    <int:transformer expression="'bar'"/>
</int:chain>

<int:chain input-channel="nonStpChannel" output-channel="systemChannel3">
    <int:transformer expression="'bar'"/>
</int:chain>

<int:channel id="systemChannel1" />
<int:channel id="systemChannel3" />

<int:outbound-channel-adapter channel="systemChannel1" ref="systemChannel1OutputHandler" method="handleMessage"/>
<bean id="systemChannel1OutputHandler" class="org.mockito.Mockito" factory-method="mock">
    <constructor-arg value="org.springframework.integration.core.MessageHandler"/>
</bean> 
<int:outbound-channel-adapter channel="systemChannel3" ref="systemChannel3OutputHandler" method="handleMessage"/>
<bean id="systemChannel3OutputHandler" class="org.mockito.Mockito" factory-method="mock">
    <constructor-arg value="org.springframework.integration.core.MessageHandler"/>
</bean>
```

.

```
@ContextConfiguration
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class Foo {

    @Autowired
    private MessageChannel headerEnriched;

    @Autowired
    private MessageHandler systemChannel1OutputHandler;

    @Autowired
    private MessageHandler systemChannel3OutputHandler;

    @Test
    public void test10() {
        Message<String> foo = MessageBuilder.withPayload("foo")
                .setHeader("messageType", "stp").build();
        headerEnriched.send(foo);
        verify(systemChannel1OutputHandler).handleMessage(any(Message.class));
    }

    @Test
    public void test30() {
        Message<String> foo = MessageBuilder.withPayload("foo")
                .setHeader("messageType", "nonStp").build();
        headerEnriched.send(foo);
        verify(systemChannel3OutputHandler).handleMessage(any(Message.class));
    }
}
```

Both tests run fine for me.

Comment: Thank for your help. I actually failed to include one bean into my context (see update), which is causing the problem. Still not clear why the issue appears though.

Comment: Since you have two consumers subscribed to 'headerEnriched', the default dispatcher will round-robin the reequests, so your second test message goes to the "new" adapter. If you really intended this dual subscription, you'll need to make 'headerEnriched' a publish-subscribe-channel.